# Foundation 5 Top Bar additional breakpoint

Tags: css, menu, sass, zurb-foundation, navigationbar

I want certain menu items not to collapse into the menu at the top-bar-breakpoint but at another breakpoint later on.

Now at my 80em breakpoint every item collapses into the menu.
But I want certain navigation items to collapse at 30em.
I figured out there are visibility classes but them put on the `<li>` or the parent `<ul>` of the items there is no effect. With trying "show-for-small-up" there is no effect. With "hide-for-medium-up" (for test purposes) the item is hidden properly.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

## **EDIT with solution:**

After studying the framework core I came up with a solution.

#### 1) In _global.scss you set additional ranges for the additional breakpoint.

```
// Media Query Ranges
$small-range: (0em, 40em) !default;
$medium-range: (40.063em, 64em) !default;
$large-range: (64.063em, 90em) !default;
$xlarge-range: (90.063em, 120em) !default;
$xxlarge-range: (120.063em, 99999999em) !default;

// The following code is the new one:
// Media Query Ranges for Top Bar
$medium-range-tb: (45.063em, 80em); // 45 to 80 ems in my case, yours will be different
$large-up-range-tb: (80.063em, 99999999em);
```

#### 2) In the same file some lines below you set new Media Queries:

```
$medium-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)})" !default;
$medium-up-tb: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range-tb)})" !default; // This one is new
$medium-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($medium-range)})" !default;

$large-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)})" !default;
$large-up-tb: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-up-range-tb)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($large-up-range-tb)})" !default; // This one is new
$large-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($large-range)})" !default;
```

#### 3) In _global.scss you need the new variables we just set:

```
// Transitions and breakpoint styles
$topbar-transition-speed: 300ms !default;
// Using rem-calc for the below breakpoint causes issues with top bar
$topbar-breakpoint: #{lower-bound($medium-range-tb)} !default; // This one is new/updated
$topbar-media-query: $medium-up-tb !default; // This one is new/updated
```

#### 4) In the same file some lines below you set a new Media Query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range-tb)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($medium-range-tb)}) {
    // Put the stuff you want to do here
    // e.g: I placed the hamburger icon mixin here
}
```

#### 5) Compile and be happy :)

Comment: please add a jsfiddle

Comment: Well, there is no need for code to show. I just want to know a certain way to add another breakpoint without totally ignoring the foundation possibilities (I know that I could set up my own media queries in my custom styles but I don´t like it that way).